# Doxygen and Objective-C Protocols

Tags: objective-c, protocols, doxygen

I'm using the Doxygen Wizard on the Mac (GUI for Doxygen 1.7.3).

I found out that If, in the header for my class, I #import a header file in which a protocol is defined, the first member of my class appears in the docs as pre-appended with the path to the class' header file, something like this:

(Doxygen HTML Output)

```
Protected Attributes:

Users [username] Desktop DirectoryName ClassName h NSString* myStringMember
```

(Further attributes display OK)

If I remove the #import, the problem goes away (But I need the protocol).

I read somewhere that Doxygen used to 'choke' on Obj-C protocols in the past, but that bug should be fixed by now. Anyone else experiencing something similar?

Comment: Looks like many have run into the same problem but no one has an answer! perhaps the doxygen authors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider [appledoc](http://gentlebytes.com/appledoc/), its targeted at Cocoa developers and produces really good output.